# Spring Security Authentication Manager (Login not working)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

i was trying to create a user register and login mechanism to register and login user, Register is working fine but login is giving **401 Unauthorized Error** while passing username and password.

> **Service Class**

```
@Override
    public ResponseEntity<BaseResponse<loginUserResponse>> loginUser(LoginUser loginUser) {
        BaseResponse<loginUserResponse> response = new BaseResponse<>();

        if (Objects.equals(loginUser.getUsername(), "") || loginUser.getUsername() == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("Invalid Username");


        System.out.println("username " + username);

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginUser.getUsername(), loginUser.getPassword()));


        System.out.println("authentication" + authentication.toString());


        response.metaData.setStatus("Successful");
        response.metaData.setError(false);



        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

> **Security Config class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource;



    @Bean
    public JdbcUserDetailsManager detailsManager() {
        return new JdbcUserDetailsManager(dataSource);
    }


    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) throws Exception {
        var authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return new ProviderManager(authProvider);
    }



    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        return httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests(auth -> auth
                        .antMatchers("/Users/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().antMatchers("/js./**", "/css/**", "/image/**");
    }


}
```

(I'm using spring security 5.7 + and i know they have change few thing from 5.7 version)

I'm using MySql database to store user details.
Also im not getting any error .

Comment: Make sure password in database is stored as Bcrypt encoded string. Also refer https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/main/servlet/java-configuration/authentication/username-password/jdbc/src/main/java/example/SecurityConfiguration.java

Comment: this is how the password is stored in db (after Bcrypt  encryption): $2a$10$aNvxHF0XPERq67/pOBcoheG2KsiPyXOot12c/ng5kQHhqFKn62bY.

Comment: Hi there, what is the `@RequestMapping` path that calls the service? I see that you have `authorizedRequests()` configured, the path might be "blocked" due to this.

Comment: the path is /Users/Login, also (System.out.println("username " + username);) statement is printing the username in the console.